# CAShapeLayer. After rotating frame coordinates update but path coordinates don't

Tags: swift, rotation, calayer

This is a bizarre one for me and after having spent two days trying to fix it and reading what I could find on apple sites and stack overflow I still have no solution. Hopefully someone can help me.

So I am rotating a CAShapeLayer which is in the coordinate system of the view. After rotation the frame-coordinates are updated but those for the path are not.

On screen the path and frame both display as rotated! So If I used path.contains to see if a point belongs the CAShapeLayer after rotation I get wrong answer. Using the rotated frame does not work because frames of adjacent paths can overlap and give wrong answer.

Here is the code that rotates the relevant CAShapeLayer:

```
            let shapeCopy = CAShapeLayer()
            let inputShape = tempShapeList[index]
            shapeCopy.backgroundColor =UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.75).cgColor
            shapeCopy.frame = inputShape.frame
            shapeCopy.bounds = inputShape.bounds
            shapeCopy.path = inputShape.path
            shapeCopy.position = inputShape.position
            shapeCopy.anchorPoint = inputShape.anchorPoint
            print("bounding rect pre rotation: \(shapeCopy.frame)")
            print("path pre rotation: \((shapeCopy.path)!)")

            let transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(75*Double.pi/180.0), 0, 0, 1)
            shapeCopy.transform = transform
            print("bounding rect post rotation:\(shapeCopy.frame)")
            print("path post rotation: \((shapeCopy.path)!)")
            if ((shapeCopy.path)!.contains(newPoint)) {
                containingView.layer.addSublayer(shapeCopy)
                answer = index
                print("Prize is:\(String(describing: textLabelList[index].text))")
                break
            }
```

The message in the debugger:

bounding rect pre rotation: (139.075809065823, 236.846930318145, 174.164592138914, 163.153069681855)
path pre rotation: Path 0x600000236a60:
moveto (207, 400)
    lineto (138.901, 266.349)
    curveto (196.803, 236.847) (267.115, 247.983) (313.066, 293.934)
    lineto (207, 400)
    closepath

bounding rect post rotation:(189.419925763055, 292.163148046286, 202.670877072107, 210.457199272682)
path post rotation: Path 0x600000236a60:
  moveto (207, 400)
    lineto (138.901, 266.349)
    curveto (196.803, 236.847) (267.115, 247.983) (313.066, 293.934)
    lineto (207, 400)
    closepath

ScreenShot of the simulator:

[Screen shot of the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjV6X.jpg)
In the screen shot you will see the rotated path and the frame of the path in the dark colored pie and slightly translucent frame.

However the coordinates of the path haven't changed. So the program believes that the red dot belongs to the shaded slice that got rotated away! If the paths updated correctly the red dot would belong to the yellow slice labelled "e6 ¢" gives wrong answers.

Also note that the background fortune wheel is a view etc in its own coordinate system. The rotated dark pie is in the coordinate system of the top level view as is the red dot.

Not sure if the post is fully clear - apologize in advance for this verbose post. If I have missed on any detail that can help please let me know.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 5):

Applying a transform to a layer doesn't change the way the layer's content is stored. If the layer contains an image, the image is stored unrotated, and if the layer contains a path, the path is stored unrotated.

Instead, when the window server builds up (“composites”) the screen image, it applies the transform as it is drawing the layer's content into the frame buffer.

The `frame` property is different. It is actually computed from several other properties: `position`, `bounds.size`, `anchorPoint`, and `transform`.

You want to test whether a point is inside the on-screen appearance of the layer's path—that is, the path with the transform applied.

One way to do this is to convert the point into the layer's coordinate system. To convert it, you also need to know the original coordinate system of the point. Then you can use `-[CALayer convertPoint:fromLayer]` or `-[CALayer convertPoint:toLayer:]`. For example, suppose you have a tap gesture recognizer and you want to know if the tap is inside the path:

```
@IBAction func tapperDidFire(_ tapper: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let newPoint = tapper.location(in: view)
    let newPointInShapeLayer = shapeLayer.convert(newPoint, from: view.layer)
    if shapeLayer.path?.contains(newPointInShapeLayer) ?? false {
        print("Hit!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Rob. That worked!! is there any place I can read more documentation on this stuff?